# bootstrap dropdown in collapse,

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I'm using Bootstrap 2.0.3, with drop-down menus inside divs which are collapsible / expandable. When the drop-down menu overflows the div, they get cut off (but they shouldn't). Jsfiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/t3wFK/1/

In Bootstrap 2.0.2 the menu does not get cut off: http://jsfiddle.net/u3wkK/

I found half a workaround by using a css rule as follows:

```
#stuff.in {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

The 'in' css class gets added by bootstrap whenever a div marked with 'collapse' gets expanded.

Unfortunately this workaround breaks completely in Firefox.

Any ideas? I am considering downgrading to Bootstrap 2.0.2, but that would be painful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem here appears to be that in 2.0.3, Bootstrap applies the `.collapse` class to the `#stuff` element. In the bootstrap css, there's a style:

```
.collapse {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, when you expand a `.collapse` target, the `overflow` property remains `hidden`.

Not sure if it's a bug or not (would have to look into it deeper to see if there's any drawbacks to doing this), but modifying the rule for `.collapse.in` would work.

```
.collapse.in {
    height: auto;  /* this style already exists in bootstrap.css */
    overflow: visible;  /* this one doesn't. Add it! */
}
```

If you would prefer not to modify Bootstrap's CSS (which may have unintended side effects as noted in the comments), you can add `shown` and `hide` event handlers to your `#stuff` element to modify the `overflow` property:

```
$('#stuff').on({
    shown: function(){
        $(this).css('overflow','visible');
    },
    hide: function(){
        $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: As with the comment to the other answer, the reason why the `overflow: hidden` is not changed is because the CSS transitions would look awful in some cases, particularly for accordions, which depend on this class.  Definitely not a bug.

Comment: Valid. I've updated my answer to use event handlers instead that only modify the `overflow` property while the `.collapse` element is fully expanded.

Comment: On a related note, I don't know that I like the fact that Bootstrap applies the `.in` class before the expansion animation, but also removes it before the collapse animation. To me, it seems it would make more sense to either apply the `.in` class so long as the element isn't hidden, or ONLY apply it if the element is completely visible.

Comment: But that's what makes the CSS3 transition work in the first place! The fact that they included both a `hide/hidden` and `show/shown` I think provides plenty of room for control, as your workaround demonstrates well.

Comment: right; i keep forgetting that they're using css3 transitions and not javascript-based animations. you're absolutely right.

Comment: I've implemented the jQuery/javascript solution described above, except using the 'hidden' event, not the 'hide' event. I don't like at all that I have to use Javascript, but also understand that it's not a bug. Thanks @jackwanders @merv!

Answer (score 4):

I've tried your workaround with Bootstrap 2.1.1 and it breaks in Firefox 16, working just for the first time then not opening at all.

In my case, the problem was only the first time a visitor opened the collapsible element and inline fixed height was applied. The second time height was set to auto.

So I've found that the problem relies on the html code for nav-collapse element wich doesn't have a state declared at first:

Here's the code at first:

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

Then after expanding first time bootstrap assigns fixed height:

```
<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: 286px;">
```

And after closing first time height back to 0:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
```

Opening second time and it works fine with auto height:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: auto;">
```

So class .collapse is needed for the javascript to set automatic height:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

It took me a while to figure out!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `!important` flag, as it seems in Firefox, properties are read with different priority for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3wFK/2/

```
.in {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: You may want to update the jsfiddle so that it includes the CSS.

Comment: I'd add the cautionary note that this will screw up transitions for things like accordion components.  If you do use this, definitely apply it with a more specific selector than merely `.in`.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a lot of research on this found a solution to the problem by adding this line of code to the css, i found this at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/2423#issuecomment-13132202

```
.collapse.in[style="height: auto;"] {overflow: visible;}
```

This did the trick for me hope this works for you