# bootstrap 3 dropdowns not visible when used inside panel collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When using the Split button dropdowns component inside a panel the options is not showing, I tried playing with the z-index but cant get the options to show above the panel edge.

Here is a plunker to demonstrate the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/3tLsR3?p=preview

I tried setting the overflow: visible; suggested here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963047/1719181 but the dropdown still not showing.

Is there some other css or javascript I can apply to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference, I ran into this issue and solved it by applying the overflow rule on the .panel class instead of .collapse.in:

```
.panel-group .panel
{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Working fork here: http://plnkr.co/edit/due3dHqQkeSDtkBqnfuW?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Delete this div and it works fine:

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" style="z-index: -1;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer yet, but I can suggest going with the "dropup" until a fix is found. I've messed around with both CSS and the bootstrap source and came up with nothing.

Comment: Tanks for taking a look!